# ASP.Net Code block not returning data

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I have a code block that does not return the expected data values.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
corpEmployee.Employee editEmp = new corpEmployee.Employee();

editEmp.EmployeeID = PatientCustomerID.Value;
corpCustomerMgr.GetEmployeeRecord(editEmp);

tboxFirstName.Text = editEmp.EmpFirstName.ToString();
tboxLastName.Text = editEmp.EmpLastName.ToString();
tboxCity.Text = editEmp.EmpCity.ToString();
tboxAddress.Text = editEmp.EmpAddrLine1.ToString();
}  


public static void GetEmployeeRecord(corpEmployee.Employee QueryData)
{
    try
    {
        List<corpEmployee.Employee> empRecord = new List<corpEmployee.Employee>();
        corpCustomerDAL.GetEmployeeData(empRecord, QueryData);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    LogAppError(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

When `corpCustomerDAL.GetEmployeeData(empRecord, QueryData);`  is executed, empRecord is returned with the Employee object with correct property values. However, when the code comes back to `corpCustomerMgr.GetEmployeeRecord(editEmp);` the employee object has null values.

How can I get the Employee object values back to the Page_Load routine?

Comment: What are you doing with `empRecord`? It doesn't seem to be used by anything. Does `GetEmployeeData` populate `QueryData` in some way?

Comment: empRecord is used to populate tboxFirstName, tboxLastName etc

Comment: GetEmployeeData does not populate QueryData. QueryData contains empID value that is used in a stored procedure to return an employee record. That record is populated in empRecord

Comment: Then the simplest thing to do is to return the populated element of `empRecord` from `GetEmployeeRecord`

Comment: Can you modify the code above to show what you mean, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, it looks like you are populating `empRecord` with the employee data you require. The simplest option is to return the populated record from `GetEmployeeRecord`:

```
public static corpEmployee.Employee GetEmployeeRecord(corpEmployee queryData)
{
    List<corpEmployee.Employee> empRecord = new List<corpEmployee.Employee>();
    corpCustomerDAL.GetEmployeeData(empRecord, QueryData);
    return empRecord.Count == 0 ? null : empRecord[0];  //or empRecord.FirstOrDefault()
}
```

You should then change the start of your `Page_Load` handler to:

```
corpEmployee.Employee queryEmp = new corpEmployee.Employee();
queryEmp.EmployeeID = PatientCustomerID.Value;

corpeEmployee.Employee editEmp = corpCustomerMgr.GetEmployeeRecord(queryEmp);
```

Comment: "corpeEmployee.Employee editEmp = ".... that's the dag gum code piece I was missing. Thanks very much Lee. It's Miller Time !!!

Answer (score 2):

You could either return the object back in the `GetEmployeeRecord` static method or you could include `ref` in front of your arguments so that you are passing the employee in as a reference instead of copying the variable.

I would recommend returning your data back vs using `ref` as your method name seems misleading, among other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Two immediate thoughts occur:

- Your exception handling needs work. You shouldn't be catching `Exception`, and you shouldn't be silently swallowing exceptions at all. It could well be that an exception is being thrown, and that's why you're not getting the data.
- You've got a `Get***` method - that should be *returning* data. It appears you're expecting the results to be put into an object... that's a confusing way of getting data out of a method. It would be clearer if your method signature were something like:

  ```
  public static Employee GetEmployeeRecord(string employeeId)
  ```

Comment: when you mention "You shouldn't be catching Exception", what would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: @DotNetRookie: Typically you catch *specific* exceptions that you can actually handle and continue from (which is pretty rare), and only put general "catch Exception" handlers at the top level of (say) a request, in order to avoid bringing down the server.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely what's happening is that your employee object that you're passing in is being copied, and is destroyed when the function terminates.
To better illustrate, I've added some comments:

```
public static void GetEmployeeRecord(corpEmployee.Employee QueryData)
{
    //QueryData is a newly created Employee here, and is NOT the same one that was passed in.
    try
    {
        List<corpEmployee.Employee> empRecord = new List<corpEmployee.Employee>();
        corpCustomerDAL.GetEmployeeData(empRecord, QueryData);//
        //QueryData now contains the data you want your original object to contain
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    LogAppError(ex.ToString());
    }
}  //when this function terminates, QueryData ceases to exist.
```

In order to fix it, pass the employee by reference (use the ref keyword) instead of passing it by value, which is what you're doing right now.

Comment: ....... "//QueryData now contains the data you want your original object to contain "..... no... QueryData does not contain the Employee object I want... empRecord contains the employee object I will use to pass to tboxFirstName, tboxLastName etc